# js jQuery, always have a number display at least two digits 00

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following to add one to number:

```
<div id="count">00</div>
<div id="count">03</div>
<div id="count">08</div>
<div id="count">12</div>

$('#count').text(function(i,txt) { return parseInt(txt, 10) + 1; });
```

I always want there two be 2 places, 00 even if the number is under 10. How can I get the func above, with JS, to always return the 2 00 places? So if the number computes to 3, it injects 03 into #count?

Thanks

Comment: FYI it is invalid to have more than a single element with the same ID. This will not valid correctly and JavaScript may behave unexpectedly on different browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#count').text(function(i,txt) { var c = parseInt(txt, 10) + 1; return (c<10) ? "0"+c : c; });
```

EDIT: But having multiple elements with the same ID is gonna cause problems somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a little different approach from the others. Doesn't use a conditional operator.

```
$('#count').text(function(i, txt) {
    return ("0" + (+txt + 1)).slice(-2);
});
```

It just assumes it will need the extra `0`, then returns a slice of the last two characters in the string.

Comment: I like this one. Much shorter than a conditional solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `"0"` if it's less than 10, like this:

```
$('#count').text(function(i,txt) { 
  var num = parseInt(txt, 10) + 1; 
  return num < 10 ? "0" + num : num;
});
```

I *think* it's just an example, but if it's not note that IDs have to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('#count').text(function(i,txt) { return txt.length == 1 ? '0'+txt : txt; });
```